# Can't get transform property of SVG element in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I have an SVG element (a d3.js chart) with a `click` event. On click, we need to get the position of the `focu`s element and then do something with this info.

```
var focus = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .style("display", "none");

svg.on("click", function() {
    var focus_el = document.getElementsByClassName('focus')[0];
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(focus_el);
    console.log(focus_el);
    console.log(style.transform);
});
```

In Chrome, the console shows:

```
<g class="focus" transform="translate(7,384)" style="display: block;">...</g>
matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 181, 357)
```

In Firefox, the console shows:

```
<g class="focus" transform="translate(7,384)" style="display: block;">...</g>
none
```

So, even though the `transform` inline style is present in both cases, and `display` is set to `block` in both cases, Firefox can't find the `transform` property in the `style` object.

If I try to get the transform property directly (`focus_el.transform`) I get different results compared to the `style.transform` approach.

output of `console.log(focus_el.transform)`:

```
SVGAnimatedTransformList {
    animVal: SVGTransformList [
        SVGTransform {
            angle: 0,
            matrix: SVGMatrix {
                a: 1, b: 0, c: 0, d: 1, e: 31, f: 382
            },
            type: 2
        }
    ],
    baseVal: SVGAnimatedTransformList [
        SVGTransform {
            angle: 0,
            matrix: SVGMatrix {
                a: 1, b: 0, c: 0, d: 1, e: 31, f: 382
            },
            type: 2
        }
    ]
}
```

output of `console.log(style.transform)`:

```
matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 193, 345)
```

Comment: In Firefox transform attributes and styles are separate, if you want to use transform as a style set it via a style attribute. If not then you'll need to treat it as an attribute only.

Comment: @RobertLongson But how do I get the value of the `transform` property then? If I try just `focus_el.transform` I get something called `SVGAnimatedTransformList`.

Comment: Perhaps there is also a d3.js native way to do this? I haven't found one in the docs though.

Comment: using the SVG DOM as you are starting to do is the way to go.

Comment: But there are two matrices inside the SVGAnimatedTransformList, and neither one matches what I have in style.transform. I still don't get it. If you care to make this an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Done. Also added the entire content on this SVG object.

Comment: I've added everything now.